# EAV_Databasesystem in Magento 1.6

Tags: magento, entity-attribute-value

I have a strange problem with Magentos EAV-Databasesystem.I want to store a dataset like the next codeblock. But one value 'StoreId' was not stored. Do you have any Idea why one of eight values can stored in a table.

```
public function populateEntriesAction()
{
    //return;
    for ( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ )
    {
        $branchEntry = Mage::getModel('branch/eavisbranch');
        $branchEntry->setName('abc ' . $i);
        $branchEntry->setStreet('abcdefg ' . $i);
                     .....
        $branchEntry->setStorePickup(false);
        $branchEntry->setStoreId('3');


        $branchEntry->save();
    }

    echo 'Done';
}
```

Comment: How do you have the StoreId attribute set up for your entity?

Comment: Have you manually deleted the `var/cache/` directory?  Some entity information is cached, even when everything is disabled.

Comment: If you don't have a store of id 3 set up yet it will fail, as that index is constrained by actual store ids.

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but it might be also not setStoreId but setStores or setStoreIds.